# cannot start windows service but can execute the command in command prompt

Tags: windows-services, command-prompt

I am currently trying to setup a windows service to start up automatically,
but seem to have some problems starting the service. 
In windows service. The executable can be executed in commandprompt, 
and runs without any problems there, but get prompted with an error message 
"Error 1053: The service did not respond to start or control request in a timely fashion"

I tried to change the timeout period (what google suggested me) with the same issue, 
besides that, I don't think that is the real issue, since the startup usually takes around 150 ms to start.

so what could cause it?
Event viewer doesn't output anything besides the error message stated above?
anything else I can test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very likely that you are trying to do the actual work in the `OnStart()` call instead of off-loading it to another thread.  The `OnStart()` is used to initialize the service, but it has to return in order for the Service Manager to update the service state at a minimum.

To do this correctly, the main loop of your service where the work is done should be put in a foreground thread that is started in the `OnStart()` callback, which allows the `OnStart()` call to return in a timely fashion.  That should prevent the error you're seeing.